# How to fix this bug in this python regex for removing unwanted words in a words list? (strings)

Tags: python, regex

I got from StackOverflow a regex for removing stop words:

```
def killStopWords(stringsList):
        pattern = re.compile("\\b(a|y|o|un|una|unas|unos|que|k|d|el|la|los|les|las|pq|xq|en|como|me|con|de)\\W", re.I)
        return [pattern.sub("", aString) for aString in stringsList]
```

However I noticed it won't work properly in some cases, for example:

```
test = killStopWords(['alegría es un amor', 'la papelería afición con ilusión'])

for k in test:
    print k
```

Will print:

```
alegríes amor
papeleríafición ilusión
```

and **not**:

```
alegría, es, amor, papelería, afición, ilusión
```

as it should

It looks like it's remove characters nexto to ones containing accents

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to match entire word with your pattern and not a part of word is it correct?

If so then you can use the pattern starting and ending with 'word boundary' i.e \b.

Something like:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(un|una)\b')
```

Comment: It works better but it still *eats* trailing ***a*** in *papelería* and *alegría*

Comment: I haven't tried it but you could try modifying the pattern to ru'\b(un|una)\b' as per https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: I noticed I might normalize the string and it would work. But anyways it's a regex thing to come over

Answer (score 0):

Strip whitespace, join with `,`.

```
print ", ".join(k.strip() for k in (l.split() for l in test))
```

Comment: That helps but doesn't fix the proper work of regex, I obtain: `alegríes amor, papeleríafición ilusión`